# Android - getType(int) is undefined for the type Cursor

Tags: java, android, cordova, cursor, phonegap-plugins

I am new on mobile development, so I decided to use Phonegap to develop my application. In my app I am using a SQLite plugin, because WebSQL is not attending my necessities. When I try to put one of the files required to use the plugin in my project, Eclipse return me errors in the following function:

```
public void processResults(Cursor cur, String query_id, String tx_id) {

    String result = "[]";
    // If query result has rows

    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        JSONArray fullresult = new JSONArray();
        String key = "";
        int colCount = cur.getColumnCount();

        // Build up JSON result object for each row
        do {
            JSONObject row = new JSONObject();
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < colCount; ++i) {
                    key = cur.getColumnName(i);
                    // for old Android SDK remove lines from HERE:
                    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
                    {
                        switch(cur.getType (i))
                        {
                            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL:
                                row.put(key, null);
                                break;
                            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
                                row.put(key, cur.getInt(i));
                                break;
                            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
                                row.put(key, cur.getFloat(i));
                                break;
                            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                                row.put(key, cur.getString(i));
                                break;
                            case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB:
                                row.put(key, cur.getBlob(i));
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else // to HERE.
                    {
                        row.put(key, cur.getString(i));
                    }
                }
                fullresult.put(row);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } while (cur.moveToNext());

        result = fullresult.toString();
    }
    if(query_id.length() > 0)
        this.sendJavascript(" SQLitePluginTransaction.queryCompleteCallback('" + tx_id + "','" + query_id + "', " + result + ");");

}
```

In the line 20 (when we have "switch(cur.getType (i))"), Eclipse returns the following error:

```
The method getType(int) is undefined for the type Cursor
```

When I saw this, I tried googling it, and on the Android's documentation says that getType is a Cursor's method.

Here is what this file imports:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.phonegap.api.Plugin;
import com.phonegap.api.PluginResult;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.*;
import android.util.Log;
```

As don't know Java, I could not figure this out and I haven't found anything on my search, but I may be missing something. I hope someone can help me, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of Android are you targeting? The [getType method was added in API 11](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getType%28int%29) (Honeycomb).

You can see this on the right hand side of the header as ('Since: API Level 11') and you may find the 'Filter by API level' box at the top of the reference pages useful.

Comment: Unfortunately you won't be able to iterate over all Cursor columns automatically pre-Honeycomb. If it's your database then you happen to know the column types (as you specified them!) otherwise it's up to the documentation to tell you. For example, the [ContactsContract.ContactsColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#DISPLAY_NAME) have given types. You'll have to adapt your code to fetch each column as the correct type.